# Logo is not appearing in navbar of bootstrap

Tags: html, css, nav

I was trying bootstrap logo in navbar and the logo is not showing I have tried many things.

I am trying `<nav>` tag I am pasting my code also I am also not using any CSS:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img class="lg" src="F:\html\musicbrand\logo1.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;" />
  </a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue maybe because of the image path

```
 <img class="lg" src="F:\html\musicbrand\logo1.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;" />
```

Make a folder name img within the folder where you have your html file
and change the src path to

```
<img class="lg" src="img/logo1.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;" />
```

Comment: image and html are in same location html location:- `"F:\html\musicbrand\homepage.html"` image location:- `F:\html\musicbrand\logo1.jpg`

Comment: I might try changing backslash to forward slash as u have done

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who have answered.
I have been able to figure out the problem as giving full path was the problem.
Again thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, but if you put your image under a folder at the same hierarchy then it will be good practise!**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img class="lg" width="130px" height="70px"src="{% static "F:\html\musicbrand\logo1.jpg"%}" style="position:relative;top:-10px">
    
        </a>
    </div>
      </nav>
```